# how to freeze a div in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing Angularjs project and I need to freeze a div in that depend on a condition. I tried to use `ng-disabled` but Its not freezing a div for me. This is the code

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-disabled="true">
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Edited :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-click="goToFunction()" ng-disabled="true">
```

now I have another problem, As you guys suggested me I can change the css. But the problem is every div has got a **ng-click** So even if it is look like disabled in css it will call to the function. So how can I prevent it?

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: what do you mean by freez?

Comment: Freeze mean disabled actually. colors are faded and with low brightness. Like button in this when check box is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/q8r4e/

Comment: You mean it just look like disabled. If yes, you can use ng-class to apply css which looks like disabled conditionally.

Comment: If I have `ng-click` in that div can I Disable that ng-click one depend on condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap3, you can use text-muted class if the div contains text and apply   styles based on a condition

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-class="{'text-muted':item.myCondition}">
```

the DIV element doesnt support the disabled attribute.

or you can use css to make the div element support that attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items" ng-disabled="item.myCondition">
```

css

```
div[disabled]{
   color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `ng-disabled` in `DIV` which in invalid. You can achieve this by applying css class conditionally like this.

```
<div class="box" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'disable-mode':item%2==0,'normal-mode':item%2!=0}">

</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4e/450/)

Comment: If I have `ng-click` in that div can I Disable that ng-click one depend on condition

Comment: No you can't. But you can have two DIV's in which one with ng-click and one without ng-click. Use ng-if with your condition so that you can achieve what you want.